# Парсинг и мониторинг почты gmail

Tags: python, django, парсер, django-rest-framework, gmail

Подскажите, как правильно подключаться к почте и спарсить письмо? Я это сделал с imap, все работает но через какое то время начинает выдавать ошибки, типо не аутентифицирован, кажется не дает gmail доступ к почте. Хотел с api gmail но он сложным кажется. Если можно покажите пример как с api gmail это сделать

Comment: Вы должны привести воспроизводимый код и пояснить ваш подход. Без этого всего вопрос не имеет смысла.

Comment: Api Gmail, на сколько я знаю, сейчас единственный оставшийся путь, по которому вам и придется пройти. Пример есть в документации. https://developers.google.com/gmail/api/quickstart/python?hl=ru.